# C++ smart pointers dereferencing - what's the overhead of checking whether it is initialized?

Tags: c++, performance, smart-pointers

All the smart pointers (for example, boost::scoped_ptr, boost::optional, std::auto_ptr and others) make assertion in order to check whether internal pointer is initialized. It's ok to dereference it some not big number of times, but what if the number of times is really big (counts million, billion times)?
For example, there's a class:

```
class A
{
public:

A( std::auto_ptr< B > _someObject )
  : m_object( _someObject ) {}

B const& getMember() const
{ return *m_object; }

private:
 boost::scoped_ptr< B > m_object;
};
```

The someObject is always not null and somewhere the getMember() is called a very big number of times. On each call, the assertion inside m_object is being made.
Is it preferable to use raw pointer instead? Of course, this will lead to the destructor creation to delete the raw pointer.
Will the assertion have some noticeable impact in such a case? Or that will still be negligible?

Comment: "such a case" is kinda vague.. You only show a single class, no usage whatsoever. Why don't you measure the time it takes and then decide if it has an impact worth caring for?

Comment: This should be trivial to look up in your library code...

Comment: I thought that asserts only ran in debug mode.

Comment: @TravisPessetto that depends on what kind of assert is used/compiler settings/.. We always leave all our own asserts on for example, as we'd rather have a customer saying "hey I get this well-defined error message" instead of "hey I have no idea what's wrong but _it doesn't work_"

Comment: I doubt you could measure the difference, but you can always wrap the header defining it in yours and set NDEBUG just to get rid of asserts there.

Comment: Surely when you build a "release" version of the code, `assert` becomes "nothing", meaning no overhead. So overhead is then ZERO.

Comment: @TravisPessetto as you can tell from that thread, there's no single right answer. And this quote says it all for us _The rule of thumb is that you should use assertions when you are trying to catch your own errors_. My own errors don't suddenly evaporate in release builds, so we leave the asserts there.

Comment: If you are only asserting things you are willing to check in release, maybe you need more asserts.  And turn existing asserts into logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile your program with `-DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS` and make the comparison. But I will venture saying that the performance penalty for **that** assertion is negligible. As @Travis said, probably the assertions are not even going into your program in Release mode.

Answer (score 4):

1. Only you can determine how much overhead is acceptable for your application.
2. As most have pointed-out, your *release* version likely won't have asserts anyway.
3. In C++11, you'd use `std::unique_ptr`, not Boost or the deprecated `std::auto_ptr`.
4. If you really want to guarantee that your code isn't going to trigger the assert, then use `get()`.

Example:

```
B const& getMember() const
{ return *m_object.get(); }
```

This will return the raw pointer for you.